# How to implement Custom user defined At Least One from dynamic checkboxlist required Validation mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a dynamic checkbox list coming from sql database,
and my model to fill this dynamic checkboxes is :

```
public class TestModel
{
    public List<CheckboxList_model> DynamicCheckbox { get; set; }
}

public class CheckboxList_model
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public int Value { get; set; }

    public Boolean Selected { get; set; }

}
```

after I fill DynamicCheckbox

this is my view

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.DynamicCheckbox.Count(); i++)
                            {
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.DynamicCheckbox [i].Selected, new { @class = "flat" })

                                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.DynamicCheckbox [i].Text)

                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DynamicCheckbox [i].Value)

                            }

                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DynamicCheckbox , "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

how can make sure that user select at least one checkbox server and client validation.

Thanks